# bazel tensorflow target name misunderstanding

Tags: tensorflow, build, bazel

I try to understand bazel dependency tree in tensorflow 2.0 project.
In tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:598 there is a target:

```
tf_cc_shared_object(  
    name = "tensorflow_cc",
```

When I try to query it with bazel

```
bazel query //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc --output location
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: no such target '//tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc': target 'libtensorflow_cc' not declared in package 'tensorflow' (did you mean 'libtensorflow.so'?) defined by projects/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD
```

Why missing target refers other target, that I don't find in the BUILD file?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be:

```sh
bazel query //tensorflow:tensorflow_cc --output location
```

which produces the following output for me:

```
[...]/tensorflow/tensorflow/BUILD:611:1: filegroup rule //tensorflow:tensorflow_cc
Loading: 0 packages loaded
```

Comment: I may use //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so as well. Do you know what is the difference between them?

Comment: because no `libtensorflow_cc` target exists. Feel like I am missing the point of your question. We can `bazel {whetever} //tensorflow:tensorflow_cc` BECAUSE of build target where `name = "tensorflow_cc"`, no such build target exists in that location with `name = "libtensorflow_cc"`

Comment: //tensorflow:tensorflow_cc, //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so - what is the difference? Why quering //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so gives me the same BUILD:598:1?

Comment: the difference is the content of the `/tensorflow/BUILD` [file](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/BUILD). This file contains a target with `name="tensorflow_cc"` but *not* a target with `name="libtensorflow_cc"`.

Comment: Ok. I got it: //tensorflow:tensorflow_cc is a tf_cc_shared_object rule, defined in tensorflow.bzl, which in turn defines native.filegroup with "//tensorflow:windows": [":%s.dll" % (name)], for windows and "//conditions:default": [":lib%s.so%s" % (name, longsuffix)], as a default. So when I query tensorflow_cc, I get "filegroup rule" target. When I query libtensorflow_cc.so, I get a "generated file" target.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted but one or other of us has fundamentally misunderstood the other! :-) You said above when you query `libtensorflow_cc` you get **ERROR: no such target** - My answer was that there IS no target in `/tensorflow/BUILD` named `libtensorflow_cc`....

Comment: Probably it's my fault. I didn't write the exact question: why missing target refers other target, that is even not defined directly in the BUILD file. Because the proposed target (libtensorflow.so) is a "generated file" target as well.